# Angularjs can't find module after optmize with requirejs optimizer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, requirejs

I have this repo [angularseed](https://github.com/neonds/angularseed) at this commit: a9ad4568bd8534b888ae5cb3bf1a7f92f66d633d  (just learning tools and libs). Maybe somebody can help me.

The problem that I have it's when I try to optimize my code with Optimizer from requirejs. Im using grunt-contrib-requirejs.

To see the problem, you must to clone the repo.

Nodejs it's mandatory.

```
https://github.com/neonds/angularseed.git
cd angularseed
npm run configure //to download deps
npm run dev //then open http://localhost:9000
npm run prod
```

When I run the prod script, it seems that ngRouter its not correctly loaded and. Can Somebody help me to find the problem?

[Error log in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78hOR.png)

Gruntfile:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  'use strict';

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');



 grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        project: {
            src: 'src',
            vendor: 'bower_components',
            build: 'build',
            dist: 'dist',
        },

        clean: {
            dist: '<%= project.dist %>',
            build: '<%= project.build %>'
        },

        jshint: {
            all: ['Gruntfile.js', '<%= project.src %>/scripts/**/*.js']
        },

        copy: {
            vendor: {
                files: [
                    {expand: true, cwd: '<%= project.vendor %>/angular/', src: ['angular.min.js', 'angular.min.js.map'], dest: '<%= project.build %>/assets/vendor/js'},
                    {expand: true, cwd: '<%= project.vendor %>/angular-route/', src: ['angular-route.min.js', 'angular-route.min.js.map'], dest: '<%= project.build %>/assets/vendor/js'},
                    {expand: true, cwd: '<%= project.vendor %>/requirejs/', src: 'require.js', dest: '<%= project.build %>/assets/vendor/js'},
                    {expand: true, cwd: '<%= project.vendor %>/jquery/dist', src: 'jquery.min.js', dest: '<%= project.build %>/assets/vendor/js'},
                    {expand: true, cwd: '<%= project.vendor %>/bootstrap/dist/', src: ['*/**.min.js', '*/**.min.js.map'], dest: '<%= project.build %>/assets/vendor/bootstrap'},
                    {expand: true, cwd: '<%= project.vendor %>/bootstrap/dist/', src: ['*/**.min.css', '*/**.min.css.map'], dest: '<%= project.build %>/assets/vendor/bootstrap'},
                    {expand: true, cwd: '<%= project.vendor %>/bootstrap/dist/fonts', src: '*', dest: '<%= project.build %>/assets/vendor/bootstrap/fonts'},
                    {expand: true, cwd: '<%= project.vendor %>/components-font-awesome/', src: ['css/*', 'fonts/*'], dest: '<%= project.build %>/assets/vendor/components-font-awesome'},
                ],
            },
            scripts: {
                files: [
                    {expand: true, cwd: '<%= project.src %>/', src: 'index.html', dest: '<%= project.build %>/'},
                    {expand: true, cwd: '<%= project.src %>/../', src: 'favicon.ico', dest: '<%= project.build %>/'},
                    {expand: true, cwd: '<%= project.src %>/scripts', src: ['**/*.js'], dest: '<%= project.build %>/assets/js'},
                    {flatten: true, expand: true, cwd: '<%= project.src %>/scripts', src: '**/*.html', dest: '<%= project.build %>/',  filter: 'isFile'},
                ],
            }

        },

        concat: {
            options: {
              separator: '\n\n',
            },

            build_css: {
                src: [
                '<%= project.src %>/**/*.css'
                ],

                dest: '<%= project.build %>/assets/css/styles.css'
            },
        },

        connect: {
                sever: {
                    options: {
                        hostname: 'localhost',
                        port: 9000,
                        base: 'build/',
                        livereload: 35729
                    }
                }
        },
        watch: {
            options: {
                livereload: true,
                dateFormat: function(time) {
                    grunt.log.writeln('The watch finished in ' + time + 'ms at' + (new Date()).toString());
                    grunt.log.writeln('Waiting for more changes...');
                }
            },
            scripts: {
                files: '<%= project.src %>/**/*.js',
                tasks: ['jshint','copy:scripts'],
            },
            styles: {
                files: '<%= project.src %>/**/*.css',
                tasks: ['concat:build_css'],
            }
        },


        requirejs: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    baseUrl: "./build/assets/js",
                    out: '<%= project.dist %>/<%= pkg.name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.min.js',
                    mainConfigFile:'./build/assets/js/main.js',
                    name: 'main'

                },
                preserveLicenseComments : false,
                optimize: "uglify"
            }
        }

        

 });


 grunt.registerTask('build', function(){
        grunt.task.run('clean');
        grunt.task.run('jshint');
        grunt.task.run('copy:vendor');
  grunt.task.run('copy:scripts');
        grunt.task.run('concat:build_css');
        grunt.task.run('connect');
        grunt.task.run('watch');
 });

    grunt.registerTask('dist', function () {
        grunt.task.run('clean');
        grunt.task.run('jshint');
        grunt.task.run('copy:vendor');
        grunt.task.run('copy:scripts');
        grunt.task.run('concat:build_css');
        grunt.task.run('requirejs');
    });
 };
```

Thanks!!

Comment: show the code of your grunt file.

Comment: Hi. I has updated the post with the grunt file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular fails because it calls `.toString()` on your functions to figure out what parameters it needs to inject. This of course immediately breaks when you minify your script. For example, instead of this:

```
appModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      template: '<home></home>'
    });
})
```

Which would get minified to something like:

```
appModule.config(function(a){a.when('/',{template:'<home></home>'})})
```

Since Angular was so poorly thought out it doesn't know that `a` in the above minified script is supposed to be `$routeProvider` so it just fails miserably when presented with this.

You need to do this:

```
appModule.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      template: '<home></home>'
    });
}])
```

You can see more explanation of why Angular breaks so easily when minified here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification

Comment: Wow!, thanks for youre time. It is good to know the problem with minification.